# Find code using [Obsolete] marked code of a list of assemblies using NDepend

Tags: .net, analysis, ndepend

I am currently trying to use NDepend to identify (our) code that uses [Obsolete] marked members of a particular group of referenced assemblies (in my example starting with "*Microsoft.TeamFoundation.**") and by "our code" I mean members of ours calling / using [Obsolete] members in said list of reference assemblies. Ideally I would get a precise list of our Type and their members but I would also be fine with just our types if I had the actual count of those [Obsolete] member usages inside those types

The idea is to do a one time analysis of the quantity of [Obsolete] member calls/usages we have, then integrate that into a CI pipeline going forward to track the reduction of that over time.

Any guidance or sample code doing something like that would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can also enable warning 618. This is generated for each use of an obsolete method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code query:

```
let obsoleteTMF = TypesAndMembers.Where(x => x.IsObsolete).ToHashSetEx()
from c in Application.Types.Concat<IUser>(Application.Methods).UsingAny(obsoleteTMF)
select new {
typeOrMethod = (ICodeElement)c,
obsoleteUsed = c.IsType? 
   c.AsType.TypesUsed.Intersect(obsoleteTMF) :

   c.AsMethod.MethodsCalled
   .Concat<IMember>(c.AsMethod.FieldsUsed)
   .Intersect(obsoleteTMF)
}
```

Thanks to calls to `Concat()` this query handles both types and methods at the same time. `.ToHashSetEx()` is used to speed up calls to `Intersect()`.

It works this way:

[image: NDepend code query to match obsolete typoe, methods and fields usage]